# How can I get date and time separately using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my table date is listed as "2015-07-31 06:02:20". How can I get date and time separately using jQuery?

I used some code but it shows some errors.

```
var timestamp = new Date(data.responsecusthistory.created_at);
var date      = timestamp.toDateString();
```

Error: Invalid Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var date = data.responsecusthistory.created_at.split(" ")[0];
var time = data.responsecusthistory.created_at.split(" ")[1];
```

Comment: Elaborate/explain your answer, what it does, how and why is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a time string (i.e. HH:MM:SS), try e.g. this:

```
var timestampTime = timestamp.toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
```

Anyway, there's no obvious reason why you get the "Error: Invalid Date", as long as

```
data.responsecusthistory.created_at
```

is a correct value, such as "2015-07-31 06:02:20". Please consider double-checking this variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

dateString= "2015-07-31 06:02:20";

temp = new Date(dateString);

dateStr= $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', temp );

for getting different formats check the link https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat.
Using different formats we will get different date, time etc in which ever forms we need it.